# Index range of data and compare to column then return first available option from same column

Tags: regex, indexing, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a range of data on `Sheet1` in `B2:K18` and a list of values on `Sheet2` in `A2:A`.

In a cell, say `Sheet1!B20`, I would like to automatically return the first value from the list in `Sheet2!A2:A` that is **not** found in the range `Sheet1!B2:K18`.

Note that `Sheet1!B2:K18` will be updated so the returned value will hopefully change if the original returned value is entered into `Sheet1!B2:K18`.

I am assuming it has to include `INDEX` and `MATCH` but I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(sheet2!A2:A, 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(sheet2!A2:A, "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, B2:K18)&"$"))), 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I actually worked something out kinda similar =INDEX(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A,COUNTIF(B2:K18,Sheet2!A2:A)=0),1)